# Is state update in getDerivedStateFromProps synchronous with the render?

Tags: reactjs, react-state-management, react-state, getderivedstatefromprops

Since `getDervivedStateFromProps` is called before *every* render, I assume the state is *guaranteed* to be updated synchronously before the render (i.e. it will not get batched with other `setState` calls like a normal `setState` call potentially would?)

In other words, any updates that occur in `getDerivedStateFromProps` are guarantee to be reflected in the following `render`?

Answer (score 1):

from React's official documentation:
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops

> **getDerivedStateFromProps** is invoked right before calling the render method, both on the initial mount and on subsequent updates. It should return an object to update the state, or null to update nothing.

also:

> Note that this method is fired on every render, regardless of the cause.

so I would say the answer is yes but I would avoid using it. Please check this: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html

Comment: it will depend on what you do in getDerivedStateFromProps for sure but it will always be called right before render. please check this example:
https://codepen.io/NadaSadek/pen/rEpOde